# Errors when trying to open an H5 file

Tags: hdf5

I am a novice with .H5 files, but I have pulled out a few files from my system at work and am trying to view them.  First [I tried in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/234400/115) since the format is now supported, but I received a very vague error that the raster was invalid. Now I downloaded HDFView and I am getting this error:

[image: HDFView_error]

I was hoping I could attach one of the files here so someone who knows more could take a look, but it doesn't look like I can do that. I'm stumped and in need of some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your H5 files have a structure that it is not supported by those programs. Maybe is the version of hdf5 that your company is using, as far as I know HDFview can't open files created with the latest version of HDF5 (hdf5 1.10). Or, your company is using a special structure to create their H5 files. For example, the .mat files used by MATLAB are based on HDF5, however, you can't open them with HDFview.

You should ask your company how other collegues are inspecting the files.

Comment: Thank you Pablo.  I think this might be the issue but am trying to find out more information.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into the same problem, I suggest the viewer from Pypi:
https://pypi.org/project/h5pyViewer/

HOWEVER:

- I only tried this on my computer (hdf5-1.10.0 on Kubuntu)
- The HMI needs a minor post-install tweak for the "File->Open" to work :
  Edit "h5pyViewer.py" and replace every "wx.OPEN" with "wx.FD_OPEN" (I found 2 instances l.130 and l.241. This is due to a library evolution that wasn't updated in the code.)
- After download&unzip, some extra libraries may be required (e.g. I had to install wxpython via anaconda, but there could be more deps)

Still too bad that HDFView doesn't update along with the libraries though :-)